# Why there is no billing address in stripe Checkout

Tags: stripe-payments

I am using Stripe Checkout for credit card charging. But I don't see billing address in the popup window. How come they don't need a billing address? Why? Any other websites that I visit asks for billing address when I am ready to pay with credit card.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Billing address support is deprecated in Stripe Checkout.

Billing address is not required for merchants to accept credit cards, it does help reduce fraud rates as the merchant can ask the bank to verify the address provided with what they have on file for the card, this is known as AVS (Address Verification Service). AVS is quite a useful tool but it only checks the numbers in an address which makes it great for things like Zip Code but not as good for checking things like city or the street address. This numbers only limitation has been known to cause many issues when verifying the street address (this is why Stripe doesn't have an auto-decline on street address failure setting).

Thus given that AVS is really only useful for Zip code, Checkout only supports collecting and checking the zip code field.

Comment: Thanks! But I don't see a zip field in the Checkout popup either... The only field I see is Email, Card number, MM/YY, CVC. and the a 'Remember me' checkbox at the end.

Comment: zip is an option? From their documentation:
`data-zip-code: Specify whether Checkout should validate the billing ZIP code (true or false). The default is false.`
My question is, is this Zip checking really important? If it is, why the default is false? Is it my website's responsibility to provide zip check (credit card fraud prevention)?

Comment: You're responsible for fraud through Chargebacks. It's up to you to decide your tolerance for fraud vs the user experience

Comment: Hi. Can I ask where you got the information about billing address support being deprecated? I've not seen any mention of this in the Stripe Checkout documentation. Thanks. https://stripe.com/docs/checkout

Comment: Its been un-deprecated.

Comment: Swift system contains billing information on transactions, including addresses.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to force business address fields for checkout :

```
billingAddressCollection: 'required',
```

More informations here : https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/customization#billing-address-collection

Answer (score 0):

In the new Stripe Checkout, see the documentation about [Tax ID collection](https://stripe.com/docs/tax/checkout/tax-ids) about this.

Specifically, when creating the Checkout Session, add these options:

```
    'tax_id_collection' => ['enabled' => true],
    'billing_address_collection' => 'required',
```