# Flutter how to add billing address with Stripe?

Tags: flutter, dart, stripe-payments

I am trying to learn how to (and best practices) to integrate Stripe into my mobile app.

I know from another post ([Why there is no billing address in stripe Checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31687257/why-there-is-no-billing-address-in-stripe-checkout)) that Stripe has deprecated Billing Address Support however, I'd still want to be able to add that functionality into my app.

Currently the code I have is:

```
Future<void> createPaymentMethod(BuildContext context,
Map<String, String> billingAddress, String name, String phoneNumber) async {

StripePayment.setStripeAccount(null);
// Here to add the credit Card
PaymentMethod paymentMethod = PaymentMethod();
paymentMethod = await StripePayment.paymentRequestWithCardForm(
   CardFormPaymentRequest(),
).then((PaymentMethod paymentMethod) {
   paymentMethod.billingDetails = BillingDetails.fromJson({
     'address': billingAddress,
     'name': name,
     'phone': phoneNumber,
 });
     return paymentMethod;
 }).catchError((e) {
     print('Error Card: ${e.toString()}');
 }); 

  paymentMethod != null
  ? processPaymentAsDirectCharge(paymentMethod, 
  context) 
  : AwesomeDialog(
          context: context,
          title: 'Uh oh! A wild error has appeared!',
          desc:
              'Seems like we cant process this card. Please double check your input or try a different card',
          animType: AnimType.SCALE,
          dialogType: DialogType.WARNING,
          btnOkOnPress: () {})
      .show();
}
```

Where I have a button that does:

```
onPressed: () {
   createPaymentMethod(
   context,
   {
     'city': cityController.text,
     'line1': streetAddressController.text,
     'postal_code': zipcodeController.text, // **postal_code does not show up for some reason**
     'state': stateController.text
   },
   fullNameController.text,
   '8007897890');
}
```

And What I got back from the paymentMethod in my console is:

```
paymentMethod: {
 created: 1599242290.0, 
 id: pm_someIdHereThatGotReplacedByThis, 
 livemode: false, 
 type: card, 
 billingDetails: {name: John Doe, 
                  phone: phoneNumber, 
                  address: {city: Doggo Town, line1: 555 Puppy Street, state: CA}}, 
 card: {addressLine1: null, addressLine2: null, brand: visa, country: US, expMonth: 4, 
 expYear: 2024, funding: credit, last4: 4242}}
```

**However, in my Logs in Stripe it shows**:

```
{
  "id": "pm_someIdHereThatGotReplacedByThis",
  "object": "payment_method",
  "billing_details": {
    "address": {
       "city": null,
       "country": "US",
       "line1": null,
       "line2": null,
       "postal_code": null,
       "state": null
    },
   "email": null,
   "name": null,
   "phone": null
 },
 "card": {
"brand": "visa",


"checks": {
  "address_line1_check": null,
  "address_postal_code_check": null,
  "cvc_check": null
},

"country": "US",
"exp_month": 4,
"exp_year": 2024,
"funding": "credit",
"generated_from": null,
"last4": "4242",
"networks": {
  "available": [
    "visa"
  ],
  "preferred": null
},
"three_d_secure_usage": {
  "supported": true
},
"wallet": null
},
"created": 1599240880,
"customer": null,
"livemode": false,
"metadata": {
},
"type": "card"
}
```

my question is:

How do I setup my function so that the "checks" and "billing_details" fields will be filled with the information provided by the customer? Should I be adding something to the function

```
paymentMethod = await StripePayment.paymentRequestWithCardForm(
    CardFormPaymentRequest()).then(...)
```

This is the field I am talking about:

```
"checks": {
  "address_line1_check": null,
  "address_postal_code_check": null,
  "cvc_check": null
},


"billing_details": {
    "address": {
       "city": null,
       "country": "US",
       "line1": null,
       "line2": null,
       "postal_code": null,
       "state": null
    },
   "email": null,
   "name": null,
   "phone": null
 },
```

Thanks

Comment: The checks won't happen until you either attach the PaymentMethod to a Customer, or you use it to attempt a charge. For the address, what does the POST body look like in your Dashboard logs?

Comment: @taintedzodiac thanks for your reply. Do you know where I can find a sample code on what you've mentioned here? "either attach the PaymentMethod to a Customer, or you use it to attempt a charge". An example is what I needed

Comment: this is in the POST body: {
  "billing_details": {
    "address": {
      "country": "US"
    }
  },
  "card": {
    "cvc": "***",
    "exp_month": "4",
    "exp_year": "24",
    "number": "************4242"
  },
  "type": "card"
}